# .NET Change Button Height on DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have circled back to this issue too many times to list what I have tried. Every time I try to search the issue I get results for changing the height of the dropdown selection 'menu', but I am trying to alter the height of the button itself so that it fills the height of the existing row. Currently I am working with static row height, but that may change to dynamic.

[image: ComboBoxColumn with too-short buttons]

Comment: You should create a custom DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and the associated DataGridViewComboBoxCell, so you can set the Cell's `[ComboBox].DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;`, handle `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem`, where you could set `e.ItemHeight = [Cell].OwningRow.Height;` -- You my also try with just a custom Cell, to use as the `CellTemplate` of a standard Column.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. DrawMode is not a member of the DataGridViewComboCoxColumn class. Even if I were to create a custom class that inherits, I can't create a property that accesses something the original class can't access as is?

Comment: It's not part of the Column, it's the Cell's `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` and the `[DataGridView].EditingControl`, which is passed to the `EditingControlShowing` event's `e.Control` reference. -- The previous description is *simplified*, you have a number of methods to override including the `Paint` event. You can see a complete example here: [Build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa730881(v=vs.80)) (to adapt to a ComboBox Cell).

Comment: You *could* handle the `CellPainting` event (and use `ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton()` to draw the ComboBox Button) and the `EditingControlShowing` event, to set the `(e.Control as ComboBox).DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable` and handle `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem` contextually, but you risk to leak the heck out of it and don't achieve the desired result anyway (plus, eventually, receive a number of exceptions caused by something that has not been considered / left over here and there).

Comment: This is the simplified method, with the implementation of the [IDataGridViewEditingControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol) Interface: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells)

Comment: Thank you for the resource link, that is going to take a minute to digest and implement.

Comment: @Paniom Have you implement it successfully? Can you share the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the effect you want, what has worked for me is inheriting DataGridView so that it knows how to draw a `Control` in the cell display rectangle. It can be *any* `Control` or `UserControl`.

In this case I made my own `EnumComboBox` ([Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/IVSoftware.Winforms.Extended.DataGridView.git) full sample) but that's not the point so much as that you can draw whatever you want in the cell bounds so why not let a custom control draw *itself* there?

[image: combo box fills height]

```
public class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellPainting(e);
        if (!((e.ColumnIndex == -1) || (e.RowIndex == -1)))
        {
            switch (Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
            {
                case nameof(Fruit.Name):
                    if (this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is EnumComboBoxExCell cbCell)
                    {
                        if (cbCell.EnumComboBox.Parent is null)
                        {
                            Controls.Add(cbCell.EnumComboBox); 
                            cbCell.EnumComboBox.SetEnumType<FruitName>();
                            cbCell.EnumComboBox.Font = DefaultCellStyle.Font;
                            cbCell.EnumComboBox.Cell = cbCell;
                            cbCell.EnumComboBox.SelectedEnumValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
                            {
                                // Bind the combo box back to the data item.
                                if(sender is EnumComboBox enumComboBox)
                                {
                                    ((Fruit)Rows[enumComboBox.Cell.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Name = (FruitName)e.Value;
                                }
                            };
                        }
                        cbCell.EnumComboBox.Bounds = GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case nameof(Fruit.Color):
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where:

```
class DataGridViewEnumComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewEnumComboBoxColumn(DataGridViewColumn col)
    {
        base.Name = col.Name;
        base.HeaderText = col.HeaderText;
        base.CellTemplate = new EnumComboBoxExCell();
    }
}
class EnumComboBoxExCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public EnumComboBox EnumComboBox { get; } = new EnumComboBox();
}
```

---

***EXAMPLE: *Main form consumer of DataGridViewEx**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 80;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView.DataSource = Fruits;
        var col = dataGridView.Columns["Name"];
        var index = col.Index;

        // Swap out the 'normal' column for DataGridViewEnumComboBoxColumn
        dataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(index);
        dataGridView.Columns.Insert(index, new DataGridViewEnumComboBoxColumn(col));

        dataGridView.Columns["Name"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView.Columns["Color"].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView.BackgroundColor;
        dataGridView.Columns["Color"].Width = 80;

        Fruits.Add(new Fruit());
        Fruits.Add(new Fruit());
        Fruits.Add(new Fruit());
    }
    BindingList<Fruit> Fruits { get; } = new BindingList<Fruit>();
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Where**

```
enum FruitType
{
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Banana,
}
```

And

```
class Fruit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Color Color
    {
        get
        {
            var fieldInfo = typeof(FruitName).GetField(Name.ToString());
            if (fieldInfo == null)
            {
                return Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                return fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ColorAttribute>().Color;
            }
        }
    }
    public FruitName Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_name, value))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(value);
                _name = value;
                // Notify 'Color' not 'Name'
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Color)));
            }
        }
    }
    FruitName _name = 0;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```